# C: Check if page in Chrome has fully loaded

Tags: c, google-chrome

I am writing a program in C automating keyboard clicks in Chrome to visit webpages. How can i check if the page i want to visit has fully loaded? I want to know if the page has loaded successfully or if a problem occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This might be off topic, but are you sure you want to do this in C? Why not use phantomjs. They have done the hard work, you could integrate that in your work, and listen for events just using injected javascript.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: I guess you meant `phantomjs`?